# New custom product type in magento, looking for an expert who can help us

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Looking for an expert in Magento and has knowledge on product types and thinks out of the box.

Case:

Our webshop sells furniture. As an example let's use a chair.

- A chair can consist out of multiple parts
- Seating
- Back seating
- Frame
- Other Accessories

All of these parts have their own stock details. The customer should not see that a chair consists out of different parts so the default magento configurable products or bundle products are not an option.

Please see the screenshot on what we would need. This will be a paid job! Any comments from the community will be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: FYI, this isn't a Magento expert recruitment site. You'll have far better luck asking very specific code or problem based question. Yours looks like a project specification and would require a very long answer.